# How can I extract the filename from a path in an Azure DevOps YAML Pipeline parameter using expressions?

Tags: azure-pipelines-yaml

In my pipeline, I use a template for uploading a file to the cloud. This template takes in a `source` parameter which provides the full path to the file to be uploaded.

I want to extract just the filename part (i.e. without all the directories) to use in the `displayName` for the upload step. How can I do this just using an [Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?source=recommendations&view=azure-devops)? There is no function to get the last part of a path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following expression:

```yaml
${{ split(format('.\{0}', parameters.source),'\')[length(split(parameters.source,'\'))] }}
```

To explain how this works:

1. We split the path into its components by splitting on the directory separator `\`:

   - `split(parameters.source,'\')`

   This produces an array of the path components.
2. The following expressions *aren't* valid, so we can't do these:

   - `arr[-1]`
   - `arr[length(arr) - 1]`
3. Instead we add another directory separator to the start of the path to get a new string:

   - `format('.\{0}', parameters.source)`
4. We split that string:

   - `split(format('.\{0}', parameters.source),'\')`

   This produces an array that is one item longer than the array produced in step 1.
5. In this new array, the index of the filename will be equal to the length of the original array:

   - `split(format('.\{0}', parameters.source),'\')[length(split(parameters.source,'\'))]`